# NGINX - dynamic proxy_cache_path directory

Tags: nginx, web-server, cache

Has anyone ever successfully configured separate cache folders for different sites?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation, [`proxy_cache_path`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_path) is valid only in the `http` context, and thus applies to the entire web server. You cannot vary it by virtual host or by any other criterion.

Comment: That is right, according to documentation it is not possible. What I am trying to do is to server different content based on the the geographic location of the users. I need to find a workaround this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Hex Click the Ask Question button and ask your question.